# Disable "auto-rotate" being checked by deafult in Adobe Illustrator Print Settings

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've found one other person asking about this, but with no answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/AdobeIllustrator/comments/goivws/auto_rotate_disable/

I'm trying to make it so the `auto-rotate` option under "Orientation" in Print Settings is *not* checked by default.  Setting is shown below:

[image]

**The Reason:** I'm working Library Makerspace that serves a large retiree population, and currently trying to remove as many road blocks for Laser Cutting as possible.  This little checkbox has been an issue.  Its effect is kind of random to people who aren't tech savvy... and even to me (it still rotates when the media size is perfectly square).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Illustrator....

I *believe* Illustrator retains the *last used* settings. But perhaps I'm wrong or Adobe has altered that recently. In any event....

<sup>(I'm using screenshots from a Legacy version here... 
but what is shown *should* be very similar in newer versions of Illustrator.)</sup>

From the menu: `Edit > Print Presets...`

A window pops up listing the print presets...

[image]

Highlight `[Default]` and click the little pencil icon in the middle of the window....

[image]

A large window will open with all the print options.

[image]

**Change** this window to whatever you want, then click `OK`.

Then click `OK` again in the presets..

Now, by default, the options you set in the large window will be set when you merely hit `Print`.

---

You can use Print presets to create any number of specialized settings. When you choose `Print` from the menu, you can choose your preset there, at the top of the print dialog window:

[image]